# Read face vectors from text file dlib c++

Tags: c++, dlib

I'm trying to read 128D face vector from text file.

1. How do you do it?
2. If I have multiple face vectors how can I read them in one variable and use it compare with the incoming faces?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to read 128D face vector from text file. How do you do it?

This depends on the format of your numbers. Are they in a format like CSV? Or maybe a descriptor format like JSON or XML? Or plain values separated by whitespace?

As an example, let's say you have a text file containing values separated by space, like this:

```
39.5 23.2 23.8 23.9 12.3
```

You can read this into a vector like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<double> faceVector; // we fill the numbers into this vector
    std::fstream fs("path/to/nums.txt", std::fstream::in ); // make the file stream
    double num;
    while (fs >> num) { // read in the number. Stops when no numbers are left
        faceVector.push_back(num); // add the number to the vector
    }
    for (double d : faceVector) {
        printf("value is %f\n", d); // print each number in the vector to see if it went right
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `std::vector` `faceVector` now contains the values from the file.

> If I have multiple face vectors how can I read them in one variable
>   and use it compare with the incoming faces?

You can compare the vectors by writing a function that takes the vectors as argument and returns a meaningful value. As an example, this function calculates the distance between two points:

```
double distance(std::vector<double> &a, std::vector<double> &b) {
    double result = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) result += (a[i] - b[i]) * (a[i] - b[i]);
    return sqrt(result);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
std::vector<double> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<double> b = { 4, 5, 6 };
printf("distance: %f", distance(a, b));
```